# Can I adjust the width of a <pre> area to fit the text?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<p>This is a test</p>
<pre>public class Car {
    protected Car() { }
    protected Car(int speed) { }
    protected void Car() { }
}</pre>
<p>Another line</p>
```

and

```
pre {
    font-family: monaco,consolas,"courier new",monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 3em;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    xwidth: 80%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

When the text displays the `<pre>` background goes the full width of the page. I have a demo here:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLVV9/)

What I would like is for the red background to stop just after the far most right character of my code. I don't want to see a big red area that extends from one side of the page to another.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to do this with CSS. I really am not sure as I cannot think what I can do.

Thanks

Comment: Could You tell us what is `xwidth`?

Comment: It was width before and then I found it didn't work so I just put the x there to make it so that parameter didn't do anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;`:

http://jsfiddle.net/hLVV9/1/

Although please check out the browser support, because it wouldn't surprise me if IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score 24):

The best solution so far :

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: This is for sure the best solution. Thank for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` and a clearing `div` to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLVV9/2/

Answer (score 0):

For that behavior you will need to `float` your `<pre>`. Floated blocks of course cause some layout changes, so you need to wrap it in another clearing block element:

```
<div class="pre-wrapper"><pre>Lorem ipsum</pre></div>

.pre-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pre-wrapper pre {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks good. But there is a small problem. I don't have access to go in and change anything in the HTML. This comes from a datastore. Is there some way I could do this without a wrapper? For example some way I could do a "clear" after the pre in CSS?

Comment: Hardly. In that case an `inline-block` is the best option, which AFAIK only IE7- can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: inline-block` should do it for FF, Safari and Chrome.
But make sure to check in all browsers and how it behaves, specially IE

Answer (score 0):

One more approach:

```
pre {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

It allows the margins to natively collapse (in contrast to `display: inline-block`). As a bonus, it works with a wide range of browsers starting with IE8 or even older.